# textfield2 will not accept enter the values until entering values in textfield1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have 2 text fields now my requirement is textfield2 will not accept enter the values until  entering values in textfield1 please help me

Comment: You should provide more information. Could you post any HTML/JavaScript code you are using for the text field operations ? Coudl you provide a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6):

Given two HTML fields:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2" disabled="disabled">
```

Bind an onchange event to the first text. The `disabled` attribute for the second text box is true if the field is disabled and false otherwise:

```
$("#txt1").change(function(){
    $("#txt2").attr("disabled", ($(this).val() === ""));
});
```

See it at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XC3qW/1/

Comment: `$("#txt1").on('keyup change', function(){
    $("#txt2").attr("disabled", null);
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#textfield2').attr('readonly', true);

  $('#textfield1').change(function(){
    $("#textfield2").attr('readonly', ($(this).val() === ""));
  });    


});
```

Comment: Instead of 'false' why not actually make it the value of the 'if' check (as per my answer). That way when it is empty again, it becomes disabled again.

Comment: Or, you could just do `$("#textfield2").attr('readonly', ($(this).val() === ""));` and dispense with the if clause

Comment: allways forget to use inline ===

Comment: Hehe. At least it was the === not == (which given the other answers seems to be gaining traction). +1

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this ?

```
textInputValue = $("#textbox1").val();
$("#textbox2").attr("disabled","disabled"); //or readonly and readonly

if(textInputValue !== "")
{
$("#textbox2").removeAttr("disabled");
}
```

or

```
$(function()
{
   $("#textbox1").keyup(function()
   {
       if(this.val() === "" || this.val().length < 6)  //less than 6 characters
       {
          $("#textbox2").attr("disabled","disabled");
       }
       else
       {
          $("#textbox2").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest thing I can think of:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
function enable()
{
  if (document.getElementById('txt1').value)
    document.getElementById('txt2').disabled = false;
  else
    document.getElementById('txt2').disabled = true;
}
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="textbox" id="txt1" onkeyup="enable()"/>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" disabled="true"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `onblur` event for this case

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" onblur="checkValue()">
<input type="text" id="txt2" disabled="disabled">
```

JS:

```
function checkValue() {
if(document.getElementById('txt1').value=="") {
document.getElementById('txt2').disabled=true;
} else {
document.getElementById('txt2').disabled=false;
}
```